# Class member function throwing error on simple range function

Tags: vba, excel, class

so I have a VBA function that keeps throwing the error 'Application-defined or object-defined error' and I can't figure out why. The function is meant to copy a block of cells from one sheet to another. I've used code like this in other areas with no problems, so don't understand why this isn't working.

```
    'update on main screen
    Public Sub mainImageUpdate(roomstring)
        set yoffset = Worksheets("Source").Range("A:A").Find(roomstring, , xlValues, xlWhole).Row
        Worksheets("Source").Range("B1:AB10").Offset(yoffset - 1, 0).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Main").Range("O5")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like a typo: Range("B0:AB10") doesn't exist. do you mean Range("B10:AB10")?

Comment: which line gives the error?

Comment: Maybe `Worksheets("Source").Range("B1:AB10").Offset(yoffset - 1, 0).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Main").Range("O5")` (you only need the top-left cell as the destination)

Comment: Maybe `Rows` instead of `Row`.  Also you should be declaring your variables.

Comment: @Jeeped it doens't make it to that line. "object variable or with block variable not set"... and the problem isn't `Rows` alone

Comment: so I forgot that VBA does not use zero index.... Fixed that but am still getting the same error?

Comment: declare you variables, confirm the value of `RoomString`.  Take off `row` for now to just return a range.  Also that has nothing to do with zero index... that's a cell's row number

Comment: It appears that the value of roomstring is not in Range("A:A").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Sub mainImageUpdate(roomstring)
Dim Y as range
set y  = Worksheets("Source").Range("A:A").Find(roomstring, , xlValues, xlWhole)  'look for it
if not y is nothing then  'did you find it?
    Worksheets("Source").Range("B10:AB10").Offset(y.row - 1, 0).Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets("Main").Range("O5")
else
      'do something?
end if
End Sub
```

Comment: Solved my problem! It wasn't that I couldn't find the string though, so was my only problem that I didn't declare the variable with Dim? What exactly does that do?

Comment: If you were always finding the string then the error was the typo in the range that Luke identified above. The Dim merely declares the variables you plan to use. You should always declare your variables and put Option Explicit at the top of each module - it will catch a range of typos and errors.

Comment: If the value of `roomstring` appeared in column A you were getting the error as  you were trying to `Set` a row number - you `Set` a reference to the cell and retrieve the row number property.  Removing the word `Set` would return the row number to `yoffset`, but would return an error if the search term wasn't found.

Comment: Darren -  Good catch - I missed that!

Comment: The `.Row` part is just off the screen with scrolling.  Missed it at first to.